# Reasons for a session got executing the same SQL for hours

Tags: oracle

I've found a situation where some sessions got executing the same `sql_id` (select) for hours (the most was 32 hours). all sessions was executing the same `sql_id`.. Looking in the database I didn't find any wait event holding the execution. Is this a application issue? or most likely in database side?
[image]

Comment: What database version, what Apache version, how much time does it take to execute that select?

Answer (score 1):

This is just too generic. From what you provided us, it is impossible to tell.

A few possible reasons:

- network wait (waiting for a dblink connection that is already dead)
- blocking wait (another transaction blocks these sessions)
- programmed wait (`DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP`)
- or session is not in wait at all but uses the CPU (inefficient PL/SQL code or SQL code/execution plan or session is simply spinning due to bug)